# Not able to use created build.lib using Vite.JS in other projects

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundler, rollup, vite

[(Link which I referred to create a library build)](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode)

Now how should I use this library build in some other project, I have created and uploaded the lib build as an npm package .

What should I add to view the library components in new Project  after *npm i*

**Steps Done**

1. **- *Package.json for library creation project***

```
  "main": "./dist/reporting-ui-component.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/reporting-ui-component.es.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/reporting-ui-component.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/reporting-ui-component.umd.js"
    }
  },
```

2. ***Output for the above library build***

> | dist
> |--- reporting-ui-component.es.js
> |--- reporting-ui-component.umd.js

3. Created a npm package an published it as an artifactory with name - **@reporting-ui-component**
4. Now I am planning to install the library in other project, but it gives an error

> Error  [plugin: vite:dep-scan] Failed to resolve entry for package
> "**@reporting-ui-component**". The package may have incorrect
> main/module/exports specified in its package.json.

Need solution on how to import this package and start working ?

Comment: The error message can also appear with libraries build with webpack. That's probably a config problem that is not accepted by vitejs.